# Динамический тип в зависимости от переданных значений объекта

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

У меня есть функция

```
interface IargsDef {
    name: string;
    default?: string;
}

function parseArgs(argsDef: IargsDef[], splitedString: string[]) {
        const parsedArgs: parseResults = {
            _: [],
        };
        if (argsDef.length > 0) {
            argsDef.forEach((arg: IargsDef) => {
                if (parsedArgs[arg.name] !== undefined) return;
                const value = splitedString.shift();
                parsedArgs[arg.name] = value || arg.default || " ";
            });
        }
        if (splitedString.length > 0) parsedArgs._ = splitedString;
        return parsedArgs;
    }
```

Пример возвращаемого значения

```
const splitedString: string[] = ["some", "args", "test"]
const argsDef: IargsDef[] = [{
    name: "command",
},
{
   name: "test" 
}
]
const result = parseArgs(argsDef, splitedString)  
------------------
result = {
_: ["test"],
command: "some",
test: "args"
}
```

Она проходит по массиву с именами аргументов и по значению ключа name создает новое свойство в объекте parsedArgs и присваивает ему значение из splitedString и если его нет, то стандартное, либо пустую строку.
Если в splitedString еще остались элементы, то все они пристраиваются свойству "_" объекта parsedArgs.

Мой вопрос состоит в том, как правильно сделать интерфейс parseResult, чтобы intellisense корректно с ним работал и было видно какие свойства доступны, сейчас оно работает только со свойством "_".

Сейчас интерфейс выглядит вот так:

```
interface parseResults extends Record<string, string | string[]> {
    _: string[];
    
}
```

Я бы забил и не стал с этим париться, но хочется, чтобы было удобнее пользоваться функцией. На английском стаке такой вопрос заминусили и только один ответ в комментариях, который совсем не помог. Возможно из-за моего отвратительного разговорного английского.

Comment: один минус - это совсем не заминусили :)

Comment: у тебя пример вывода не соответствует твоему коду. `splitedString` - это массив, ты его присваиваешь свойству `_` - как у тебя в результате могла получиться строка `_: "test",`?

Comment: Да это опечатка, я исправил. Но вообще, судя по тому, что ни здесь ни там не ответили, то что я хочу сделать невозможно

Comment: Почему? Тебе в принципе ответили и дали ссылку на пример реализации. Посмотри пример с ZipArray это фактически и есть твой случай

Comment: также искал ответ на такой вопрос и нашел случайно, при создании указываешь, что он может быть или такой или такой.
let updateData!: type1 | type2;
и по условию меняешь.
Исправьте если не прав.